# Inject custom Application class

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt and am trying to inject my Application into another activity:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public class MyApplication extends Application {
...
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    protected MyApplication application;
...
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.test.MyApplication cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
```

I think I can write a provider for MyApplication, but I thought Hilt by default already does that.  Assuming that I could inject the base "Application" class, but I would like to get my overridden application class.  Without of course casting it every time I want to use it.

Comment: Why you want to access my application class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hilt provides you only with `Application` class instance, this instance is seeded to the `Singleton` component after the plugin rewrites your `MyApplication` class.

You can create your own module that will do the casting from `Application` object and reuse it by setting the module to work in Singleton component.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(Singleton::class)
class MyApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    fun providesString(application: MyApplication): String {
        return application.toString()
    }

    @Provides fun providesMyApplicationInstance(application: Application) : MyApplication = application as MyApplication
}
```